# Notepad++ compare plugin - ignore comments?

Tags: plugins, compare, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ compare plugin.
I see the option to ignore spaces.

Is there a way to ignore empty lines or comments?

Thank you.
David

Comment: I would suggest that you give BeyondCompare a try. While this is a paid software, they do have a free trial, and this product does wonders when you are wanting to do more than just a simple baseline compare, especially if you want to compare directories.  https://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: If you're not keen on spending money then you could also take a look at WinMerge: 
http://winmerge.org/?lang=en  - It has filters that you can use to ignore comments, line endings and different kinds of whitespace. What you're asking for is probably beyond the scope of the 'Compare' plugin.

If you did want to complete the whole diff operation in Notepad++, can imagine you'd need to create a few temporary files and run some search/replaces on them first :)

Comment: Which version of Notepad++ ?